# define String concat ios

Tags: objective-c

I have a `#define hhh "uu"` then I want to concat string using the following method:

```
NSString *str [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@%@",hhh,"ii"];
```

but I'm getting a compilation error.

Comment: exected ) before , token

Comment: learn syntax of the language atleast before attempting to code..

Answer (score 2):

First problem: you are missing the colon `:` after `stringWithFormat`. Second problem: you are missing the assignment operator between variable name `str` and initialization expression.

Third problem: the second argument to the format string `@"%@%@"` is a plain standard C string (a.k.a., `char*`), where the format string calls for an object (a.k.a., `NSString`). Prepend a `@` to the string literal:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@",hhh,@"ii"];
```

(**Edit** Assumption wrong, I overlooked the `define`: I assume here, that `hhh` is an object reference, e.g., `id`, `NSString*` or something).

Since `hhh` is a plain string, too, you should specify `%s` as placeholder in the format string:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s%@",hhh,@"ii"];
```

as was recommended by @sch.

Comment: The first argument is also a c string, the define doesn't have an @ either